# Space between Voronoi shapes

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials

I am trying to create a material that looks like the red material in the image below, more specifically the displacement of the red material.

[image]

I have a node set up like this at the moment. I have tried mixing it with different textures, changing the mapping values and even using a displacement modifier and mixing with a Voronoi texture. However, the closest I seem to be able to get is the simple set up below, and that is nowhere near close.

[image]

I would appreciate any help improving it to get the desired output.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Final result:

[image: final]

### Node setup:

[image: node]

### Final thoughts:

It's not the same as **Voronoi Texture** but it's fast and pretty simple.
You can play with **Wave Texture's** (both of them) values to get more jagged/smoother cracks.

I've used **Bump** but you can connect it to Displacement if you need.

### Blend file:

[image]

Comment: Your welcome. If you really want to make it with Voronoi, you can check here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52284/voronoi-cracks-fac/ but, well... You will see why I make it another way :)