# How do I create a bumpy reflective material?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, light

I'm doing a project for practice, and I want to recreate this lighting shown below. I don't know too much about nodes and node setups (I'm currently studying it). I believe I have the appropriate light for this scene, I just need to know what nodes or settings to use.

*Effect I'm trying to achieve*
[image: That is how i want to look like]

Comment: Can you post a screen grab of your model? And are you using Blender Internal or Cycles render engine?

Comment: You can check my answer here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76369/space-between-voronoi-shapes/76382#76382 just change Diffuse Color and Cracks Scale in Mapping node.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stack Exchange! In order for us to help you, please provide more information. Screenshots of your node setup would be helpful, or it would be great if you can provide us your .BLEND file using [this website](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a bumpy reflective material is easy using procedural textures and bump nodes.

**Step 1:** Make sure that you are using *Cycles Render*
[image]

**Step 2:** Add a *Bump* Node With <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, and under *Vector* choose *Bump*.

**Step 3:** Connect the ***Normal*** ***output*** **of the** ***Bump*** **node** with the ***Normal input* of the Material you are using** (In most cases this will be a Diffuse material.)

**Step 4:** Add a *Voronoi Texture* node with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, and under *Texture* choose *Voronoi Texture*.

**Step 5:** Connect the ***Fac output* of the *Voronoi Texture* node** with the ***Height input* of the *Bump* node.**
*You'll notice that this already begins to warp the lighting effects on your model the way that you would want them to.*

**Step 5:** Now you just have to adjust the *Scale* value of the *Voronoi Texture* node to your liking.
Also, adjust the *Strength* value on the *Bump* node, so that the effect on the lighting isn't as harsh.

**Your end node setup should look something like this:**
[image]

**Note:** This same process applies for any other Texture node, I just used Voronoi for example because it looks close to the effect OP is trying to achieve.