# How to make a glossy bumpy material

Tags: materials

I am making a glossy book cover and would like to reproduce this effect in Blender:

[image]

Any suggestions on making the material with this sort of bumpiness?

I've tried doing something similar to suggestion at following link but I wasn't able to come to close to this effect:
[How do I create a bumpy reflective material?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78076/how-do-i-create-a-bumpy-reflective-material)

Here is what I've attempted so far, it's not quite there:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: please share the shader node setup you've already tried and are working on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close - I suggest swapping the *Voronoi Texture* with a *Noise Texture*, lowering the influence by mixing it with white before the *Bump Node*. I also changed the *BaseColor* to almost black (looks like it's black in the example image). Roughness looks good at around .1:

[image: BumpBook]

Comment: This helps, thanks!
I did have to use 0.1 for the Noise Texture Scale otherwise it looked very grainy at 14. Does that sound right?

Comment: The scale is relative to the size of your object - pick whatever scale looks best for you, even if it's different from mine. The idea is just to use a Noise texture as a basis for bump (Instead of Voronoi).

Comment: Makes sense, sorry I'm new to Blender just hacking something together. Thanks again!