# Irregular shapes texture

Tags: texturing, node-editor, procedural

Below is the type of texture I wish to generate using Blender's node system.

[image: Desired outcome]

Thus far, I have tried using a mixture of Blender's base textures, noise, magic, voronoi etc. I have attempted to combine them, modifying with various math operations, colour ramps, distorting them with vector inputs ([is it possible to distort a voronoi texture like the wave textures distortion slider?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45892/is-it-possible-to-distort-a-voronoi-texture-like-the-wave-textures-distortion-sl)), yet, can't seem to get close to what I desire.

I would greatly appreciate a node setup that would enable me to achieve said looking texture. Cheers.

**EDIT**

Since posting this question, I experimented with the voronoi cracks node ([Space between Voronoi shapes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76369/space-between-voronoi-shapes)) to try and reproduce my desired texture, it was also ever so kindly suggested to me by, Duarte Farrajota Ramos.

Granted, this is close, but not the same as what I am hoping to achieve. The voronoi cracks produces an image with pointed corners, for lack of a better word, whereas in what I want to produce has rounded edges. Additionally, the Voronoi cracks produces shapes of vastly different sizes, my desired outcome, however; produces shapes that are roughly the same size as one another, with minimal differences in size.

Comment: Download a 1 year trial for Substance Designer, it has a node (cells2 ?) that makes that pattern in b/w. Then look up how to apply "random grayscale" to those cells. Export output as .png.

Comment: Granted, yes, that'd work, however; I'm looking for a means of doing this strictly within Blender. Nonetheless, thank you for your input :)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76369/space-between-voronoi-shapes and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76369/space-between-voronoi-shapes

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52284/voronoi-cracks-fac/

Answer (score 2):

ik this is an old question but

You can get a similar pattern if you compare the `F1` output of a voronoi texture to the `Smooth F1` (of a similar voronoi). Throw in an `Add` node to offset one of them (adjust parameters to taste)

[image]

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Here is the blend file you can download:
[image]
How I made this?

- Basically, I used the 2D version of the voronoi textures.
- That allows me to have clean shapes.
  Now, to create the rounded edges, instead of doing less than with both the voronoi nodes (one f1 and other smooth f1), you need to use logarithm. And then by adjusting the smoothness parameter, you can control how smooth edges you want. By using logarithm, we are able to maintain the gradients of the shapes.
  Then, I used a technique to create the effect where some shapes have
  both some sharp and round corners. Using an RGB curve, I was able to give it some more definition by tweaking it and distorting it like in the original picture. I used bump for the height  and added a noise for realism.

Comment: Stack Exchange answers should explain what was done.  Can you add some text explaining how your blend file works, please?