# Dilate/expand vertex color mask?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, workflow, masking, vertex-colors

I'd like to use *vertex colors* in order to apply different shaders on a single object, instead of going through the whole process and drawing a 'black and white' texture (for 1000+ objects).

[image]

Obviously, the only limitation is that the mask shape depends on the topology of the object, so I'd like to know if there is a simple way to shift the edge in- or outwards (green shape in the picture).

**Q:** Is there any mechanism to dilate the shape?

Comment: Vertex color is held in the geometry - so limited geometry means you are stuck unless you add a new edge loop to help add to the vertex color range.

Comment: I'd like to avoid painting. The question is how to expand the shape within the shader tree for basically [this purpose](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/516/add-different-materials-to-different-parts-of-a-mesh). Thanks anyway @MrZak

Comment: You could of course convert paint to vertex group with WeightToVertexColors addon, and in Edit mode select that group and press Ctrl+Numpad+ to increase selection, but that's highly unefficient workflow for mixing materials as it will heavily depend on topology; vertex paint can't be called as efficient paint tool as well.

Comment: If it was possible to do some kind of "boolean painting" can that be a solution?

Comment: Following the several comments, and as I imagine most of the keycaps are similar, do you know that you can transfer vcol from active to selected (so a batch transfer)?

Comment: Yep, there is a nice answer over here, can't find it at the moment... thanks @lemon

Comment: @brockmann, but this last idea does not fit with the question!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This cannot be done in shader nodes, because to *Dilate* (paint) a point on surface one must know the color of surrounding area of that point. The node that samples Vertex Color does not allow for mapping vectors input to sample surrounding area:

[image]

That said, dilation/erosion on procedural or image textures would be possible using a dilation/erosion morphology kernel - similar to this edge detection:

[Voronoi Cracks Fac?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/52326/7777)

So to do this on Vertex Colors, it has to be done on vertex/mesh level. I wrote you a little plugin that will work on all selected objects:

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Vertex Color Expand",
    "author": "Jerryno",
    "version": (1, 0),
    "blender": (2, 78, 0),
    "location": "View3D > Toolshelf > Vertex Color Expand",
    "description": "Dilate/Expand a vertex color",
    "warning": "",
    "wiki_url": "",
    "category": "Mesh",
    }

import bpy

def dilate(mesh, layer_name, color):
    if layer_name not in mesh.vertex_colors:
        return

    polys_to_be_painted = [False] * len(mesh.polygons)
    verts_to_be_painted = [False] * len(mesh.vertices)

    for poly_id in range(len(mesh.polygons)):
        for id, loop_id in enumerate(mesh.polygons[poly_id].loop_indices):
            vert_id = mesh.polygons[poly_id].vertices[id]
            if mesh.vertex_colors[layer_name].data[loop_id].color == color:
                polys_to_be_painted[poly_id] = True
                verts_to_be_painted[vert_id] = True

    for poly_id in range(len(mesh.polygons)):
        for id, loop_id in enumerate(mesh.polygons[poly_id].loop_indices):
            vert_id = mesh.polygons[poly_id].vertices[id]
            if polys_to_be_painted[poly_id] or verts_to_be_painted[vert_id]:
                mesh.vertex_colors[layer_name].data[loop_id].color = color
    return

class VCDilate(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "vertex_colors_dilate.dilate"
    bl_label = "Dilate/Expand"
    bl_description = ""

    def execute(self, context):
        for ob in context.selected_objects:
            dilate(ob.data,
                   context.scene.vertex_colors_dilate.layer_name,
                   context.scene.vertex_colors_dilate.color)
        return{'FINISHED'}

class VCDilateUI(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Vertex Color Dilate/Expand UI Panel"""
    bl_label = "Dilate/Expand"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "TOOLS"
    bl_category = "Vertex Colors"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        col = layout.column()
        col.label(text="Target Layer:")
        col.prop(context.scene.vertex_colors_dilate, "layer_name", text="")
        col = layout.column()
        col.label(text="Target Color:")
        col.prop(context.scene.vertex_colors_dilate, "color", text="")
        col = layout.column(align = True)
        col.label(text="For All Selected Objects:")
        col.operator("vertex_colors_dilate.dilate")

class VCDilateProps(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    layer_name = bpy.props.StringProperty(default="Col")
    color = bpy.props.FloatVectorProperty(default=(1.0, 1.0, 1.0), subtype='COLOR', soft_min=0, soft_max=1)

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(VCDilateUI)
    bpy.utils.register_class(VCDilateProps)
    bpy.utils.register_class(VCDilate)
    bpy.types.Scene.vertex_colors_dilate = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=VCDilateProps)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(VCDilateUI)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(VCDilateProps)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(VCDilate)
    del bpy.types.Scene.vertex_colors_dilate

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

**Edit: does not work in 2.8**

I propose another approach which is not vertex colors based, mainly because vertex colors influence is limited by the inner geometry of the mesh.

Instead, we can use some kind of "cut mask", which allow to do the following:

[image]

It can be used also with more complex shapes, as soon as a boolean intersect (same as the operation in edit mode) can be applied:

[image]

[image]

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Generate a mask on a texture using boolean operation",
    "author": "lemon",
    "version": (1, 0),
    "blender": (2, 78, 0),
    "location": "3D View > Scene properties > Cut masks",
    "description": "",
    "warning": "",
    "wiki_url": "",
    "category": "Mesh"}

import bpy, bmesh, bgl
from mathutils import Color

def Find( l, name ):
    index = l.find( name )
    if index == -1:
        return None
    return l[index]

def GetSelection():
    return bpy.context.active_object, bpy.context.selected_objects

def RestoreSelection( active, selected ):
    active.select = True
    for o in selected: o.select = True
    bpy.context.scene.objects.active = active


def BGLInit( imageWidth, imageHeight ):
    bgl.glDisable( bgl.GL_SCISSOR_TEST )
    bgl.glViewport( 0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight )

    bgl.glMatrixMode( bgl.GL_PROJECTION )
    bgl.glLoadIdentity()
    bgl.gluOrtho2D( 0, imageWidth, 0, imageHeight )
    bgl.glEnable( bgl.GL_TEXTURE_2D )

def BGLToDefault():
    bgl.glEnable( bgl.GL_SCISSOR_TEST )
    bgl.glLineWidth( 1 )
    bgl.glDisable( bgl.GL_BLEND )
    bgl.glColor4f( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 )

def PaintMask( cutObjects, colors, defaultColor, uvMapName, imageName, borderSize ):

    image = Find( bpy.data.images, imageName )

    if image is None:
        return { 'INCORRECT' }

    imageWidth = image.size[0]
    imageHeight = image.size[1]

    BGLInit( imageWidth, imageHeight )

    try:
        buffer = bgl.Buffer( bgl.GL_FLOAT, imageWidth * imageHeight * 4 )

        bgl.glClearColor( *defaultColor, 0 )
        bgl.glClear( bgl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | bgl.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT )

        bgl.glLineWidth( 2 * borderSize )

        for obj, color in zip( cutObjects, colors ):

            uvMap = Find( obj.data.uv_layers, uvMapName )

            if uvMap:

                bgl.glColor3f( *color )

                for polygon in obj.data.polygons:

                    bgl.glBegin( bgl.GL_POLYGON )

                    for x, y in [uvMap.data[vIndex].uv for vIndex in polygon.loop_indices]:
                        bgl.glVertex2f( x * imageWidth, y * imageHeight )

                    bgl.glEnd()

                    if borderSize > 0:                    
                        bgl.glBegin( bgl.GL_LINE_LOOP )

                        for x, y in [uvMap.data[vIndex].uv for vIndex in polygon.loop_indices]:
                            bgl.glVertex2f( x * imageWidth, y * imageHeight )

                        bgl.glEnd()

        bgl.glFinish()

        bgl.glReadPixels( 0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight, bgl.GL_RGBA, bgl.GL_FLOAT, buffer )
        image.pixels = buffer[:]    
        del buffer

    finally:
        BGLToDefault()    

    return {'DONE'}

def MakeCopy( obj ):
    newObj = obj.copy()
    newObj.data = obj.data.copy()
    bpy.context.scene.objects.link( newObj )
    return newObj

def SelectVertices( obj, mode ):
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set( mode = 'OBJECT' )
    bpy.context.scene.objects.active = obj
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set( mode = 'EDIT' )
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_all( action = mode )

def TriangulateMesh( obj ):
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set( mode = 'OBJECT' )
    bm = bmesh.new()
    bm.from_mesh( obj.data )
    bmesh.ops.triangulate( bm, faces=bm.faces[:] )
    bm.to_mesh( obj.data )
    bm.free()
    del bm

def MakeCut( obj, cutter ):
    bpy.context.scene.objects.active = obj
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set( mode = 'OBJECT' )
    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')

    SelectVertices( cutter, 'SELECT' )
    SelectVertices( obj, 'DESELECT' )

    bpy.ops.object.mode_set( mode = 'OBJECT' )
    cutter.select = True
    obj.select = True
    bpy.context.scene.objects.active = obj
    bpy.ops.object.join()

    try:    
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set( mode = 'EDIT' )
        bpy.ops.mesh.intersect_boolean( operation = 'INTERSECT' )
        TriangulateMesh( obj )        
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set( mode = 'OBJECT' )
        return obj
    except:
        DeleteObjects( [obj, cutter] )        
        return None

def MakeCuts( obj, cutters ):
    newObjects = [MakeCopy( o ) for o in [obj]*len(cutters)]
    newCutters = [MakeCopy( o ) for o in cutters]
    return [MakeCut( o, cutter ) for o, cutter in zip(newObjects, newCutters)]        

def DeleteObjects( objects ):
    try:
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set( mode = 'OBJECT' )
        for o in [o for o in objects if o]:
            o.select = True
            bpy.context.scene.objects.active = o   
            bpy.ops.object.delete()
    except:
        pass

def CreateMasks( obj, selectedObjects, colors, defaultColor, uvMapName, imageName, borderSize ):

    cutObjects = MakeCuts( obj, selectedObjects )

    PaintMask( cutObjects, colors, defaultColor, uvMapName, imageName, borderSize )

    DeleteObjects( cutObjects )

def GetTargetFromScene( scn ):
    obj = None
    try:
        if scn.cutMaskUseActive:
            obj = scn.objects.active
        else:
            obj = scn.objects[scn.cutMaskObject]
    except:
        pass
    return obj

class CutMaskApply( bpy.types.Operator ):
    bl_idname = "cutmask.apply"
    bl_label = ""
    bl_options = {'REGISTER'}

    @classmethod
    def poll(self, context):

        scn = context.scene

        if not context.mode == 'OBJECT':
            #scn.cutMaskError = "Must be in object mode"
            return False

        obj = GetTargetFromScene( scn )

        if not obj or obj.type != 'MESH' or scn.cutMaskObjectUVMap not in obj.data.uv_layers:
            #CutMaskApply(context).report({'INFO'}, "No mesh target object")
            return False

        if scn.cutMaskObjectUVMap not in obj.data.uv_layers:
            #scn.cutMaskError = "Uv map undefined in target"
            return False

        if scn.cutMaskImage not in bpy.data.images:
            #scn.cutMaskError = "Image mask undefined"
            return False

        cutterNames = [elt.name for elt in scn.cutMasks]

        if obj.name in cutterNames:
            #scn.cutMaskError = "Target object cannot cut itself"
            return False

        for name in cutterNames:
            if name not in scn.objects:                
                #scn.cutMaskError = name + " is undefined"
                return False
            elif scn.objects[name].type != 'MESH':
                #scn.cutMaskError = name + " is not a mesh"
                return False
            elif scn.objects[name].data.uv_layers:
                #scn.cutMaskError = "Warning: " + name + " has a UV layer"
                pass

        return True

    def invoke(self, context, event):

        wasActive, wereSelected = GetSelection()

        scn = context.scene

        objName = scn.cutMaskObject
        distance = scn.cutMaskDistance
        uvMapName = scn.cutMaskObjectUVMap
        imageName = scn.cutMaskImage

        cutterNames = [elt.name for elt in scn.cutMasks]
        cutterColors = [elt.color for elt in scn.cutMasks]
        defaultColor = scn.cutMaskDefaultColor

        try:
            obj = GetTargetFromScene( scn )
            cutters = [scn.objects[c] for c in cutterNames]

            if obj.type == 'MESH' and all( o.type == 'MESH' for o in cutters ):
                CreateMasks( obj, cutters, cutterColors, defaultColor, uvMapName, imageName, distance )
#        except:
#            print( "error level 1" )
        finally:
            RestoreSelection( wasActive, wereSelected )

        return { 'FINISHED' }


class CutMaskListActions( bpy.types.Operator ):
    bl_idname = "cutmask.list_action"
    bl_label = ""

    action = bpy.props.EnumProperty( items = ( ('UP', "Up", ""), ('DOWN', "Down", ""), ('REMOVE', "Remove", ""), ('ADD', "Add", ""), ) )

    def invoke(self, context, event):

        scn = context.scene
        idx = scn.cutMaskIndex

        if self.action == 'DOWN' and idx < len(scn.cutMasks) - 1:
            scn.cutMasks.move( idx, idx + 1 )
            scn.cutMaskIndex += 1

        elif self.action == 'UP' and idx > 0:
            scn.cutMasks.move( idx, idx - 1 )
            scn.cutMaskIndex -= 1

        elif self.action == 'REMOVE':
            scn.cutMasks.remove(scn.cutMaskIndex)
            scn.cutMaskIndex -= 1

        elif self.action == 'ADD':
            for o in [o for o in bpy.context.selected_objects if o.name not in [cm.name for cm in scn.cutMasks]]:
                item = scn.cutMasks.add()
                item.name = o.name
            scn.cutMaskIndex = len(scn.cutMasks) - 1

        return {"FINISHED"}

class CutMaskItems( bpy.types.UIList ):

    def draw_item(self, context, layout, data, item, icon, active_data, active_propname, index):
        split = layout.split(0.6)
        split.prop( item, "name", text="", emboss=False, translate=False )
        split.prop( item, "color", text="" )

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        pass   

class CutMaskPanel( bpy.types.Panel ):
    bl_idname = 'OBJECT_PT_my_panel'
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_label = "Cut masks"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        scn = bpy.context.scene

        row = layout.row()
        row.template_list( "CutMaskItems", "", scn, "cutMasks", scn, "cutMaskIndex", rows=3 )

        col = row.column( align = True )
        col.operator( "cutmask.list_action", icon='ZOOMIN', text="" ).action = 'ADD'
        col.operator( "cutmask.list_action", icon='ZOOMOUT', text="" ).action = 'REMOVE'
        col.separator()
        col.operator( "cutmask.list_action", icon='TRIA_UP', text="" ).action = 'UP'
        col.operator( "cutmask.list_action", icon='TRIA_DOWN', text="" ).action = 'DOWN'

        layout.row().prop( scn, "cutMaskDefaultColor", text="Default color" )

        layout.row().prop( scn, "cutMaskUseActive", text="Active object as target" )
        if not scn.cutMaskUseActive:
            layout.row().prop_search( scn, "cutMaskObject", scn, "objects", text="Target" )

        obj = None
        try:
            obj = scn.objects[scn.cutMaskObject]
        except:
            pass
        if obj:
            layout.row().prop_search( scn, "cutMaskObjectUVMap", obj.data, "uv_layers", text="UV map" )
        else:
            layout.row().prop( scn, "cutMaskObjectUVMap", text="UV map" )

        layout.row().prop_search( scn, "cutMaskImage", bpy.data, "images", text="Mask" )

        layout.row().prop( scn, "cutMaskDistance", text="UV margin" )

        layout.row().operator( "cutmask.apply", text="Apply" )

        if len( scn.cutMaskError ) > 0:
            pass

class CutMaskListProp( bpy.types.PropertyGroup ):
    name = bpy.props.StringProperty()
    color = bpy.props.FloatVectorProperty( subtype = 'COLOR', default = (1.0, 1.0, 1.0), min = 0.0, max = 1.0, description = "color picker" )

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)
    bpy.types.Scene.cutMaskUseActive = bpy.props.BoolProperty()
    bpy.types.Scene.cutMaskObject = bpy.props.StringProperty()
    bpy.types.Scene.cutMaskObjectUVMap = bpy.props.StringProperty()
    bpy.types.Scene.cutMaskImage = bpy.props.StringProperty()
    bpy.types.Scene.cutMasks = bpy.props.CollectionProperty( type = CutMaskListProp )
    bpy.types.Scene.cutMaskIndex = bpy.props.IntProperty()
    bpy.types.Scene.cutMaskDistance = bpy.props.IntProperty( default = 1, min = 0 )
    bpy.types.Scene.cutMaskDefaultColor = bpy.props.FloatVectorProperty( subtype = 'COLOR', default = (1.0, 1.0, 1.0), min = 0.0, max = 1.0, description = "color picker" )
    bpy.types.Scene.cutMaskError = bpy.props.StringProperty()

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_module(__name__)
    del bpy.types.Scene.cutMaskObject
    del bpy.types.Scene.cutMaskObjectUVMap
    del bpy.types.Scene.cutMaskImage
    del bpy.types.Scene.cutMasks
    del bpy.types.Scene.cutMaskIndex
    del bpy.types.Scene.cutMaskDistance
    del bpy.types.Scene.cutMaskDefaultColor

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: That's a really clever and especially fast approach, but typically you want a nice transition between the shaders (fading out the color). Is there any chance fading out the mask or blur the image at least, with e.g. some slider? If not, I'm sure this approach drastically improves the workflow of other users however, using this as a base for further paint work so *much thanks for your effort*, it's a sweet addon @lemon.

Comment: @brockmann, this is the object of http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76890/how-to-activate-smoothing-in-bgl-opengl... so if I get an answer, I will update this one! But for a progressive or falloff fading... this is another story!!

Comment: @brockmann it would be best to ask the question a bit generally/differently, you might get more creative solutions like lemons, rather than exact answers like mine. For example I have no idea what you are trying to do, there might be some even more elegant way;) You can Gaussian_smooth any texture in Cycles like this: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/10544/7777

Comment: @Jerryno I agree. My answer was a guess. And as often we don't have a real overview of the real need. But the question is interesting. Please @ brockman don't hesitate to complete your question

Comment: Thanks guys! In general I'm interested in the most generic way adding different shaders to different parts of an object without painting. To provide an example, my actual goal is shading hundreds of keycaps for several close-ups @Jerryno. Their topology is nearly the same for all caps, regardless of whether it's tab, backspace or something. However the [top surface is quite bumpy](https://goo.gl/w1CbWD), more rough than the rest of the surface with a nice soft transition. I did some research before and using vertex colors seems ideal for that job, since no additional maps are requiered.

Comment: @brockmann, so which part of the keycaps are to be shaded using this technics? The transition between the bumpy part and the others?

Comment: Yeah, I'm using vertex colors as 'black and white mask' via attribute node and plug the color output into the fac input of a mix shader @lemon

Comment: @brockmann... so I am wondering if using the same principle as in my answer but to assign vertex color (not to make a mask)... what do you think about it?

Comment: @brockmann if those key-caps are all same height you could also use the object's Z mapping coord (scaled down to 0..1 range) as input into ColorRamp for the mask. Then you would avoid any vert_colors or textures. With a bit of math it could be upgraded to mask the same absolute height from the top of the key-cap regardless how tall it is. But if you need to mask the center also, that would not work like this.

Comment: That's a great idea too, but I don't want to waste your time - if that's ok for you I'll try to implement that for you/us next week or something... Again, thanks for your answer @lemon

Comment: Thanks @Jerryno, that sounds interesting ;) They have different heights per row on the keyboard but if we could avoid all additional maps with that, would great indeed. I have to work in the next days, but after that I'll try it and let you know... Thanks again, It's awesome to have you here guys.