# How to activate smoothing in bgl (opengl)?

Tags: python, opengl

All is in the title. I'm not able to make smoothing work, when drawing on a texture.

Here is the code before the drawing:

```
bgl.glDisable( bgl.GL_SCISSOR_TEST )
bgl.glViewport( 0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight )

bgl.glMatrixMode( bgl.GL_PROJECTION )
bgl.glLoadIdentity()
bgl.gluOrtho2D( 0, imageWidth, 0, imageHeight )
bgl.glEnable( bgl.GL_TEXTURE_2D )
```

Then:

```
    bgl.glClearColor( *defaultColor, 0 )
    bgl.glClear( bgl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | bgl.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT )
```

And:

```
                bgl.glEnable( bgl.GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH )
                bgl.glHint( bgl.GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH_HINT, bgl.GL_NICEST )
                bgl.glBegin( bgl.GL_POLYGON )
                ...
```

But the result is:

[image]

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution?

Comment: @ВладКиндюшов... no I didn't.