# Expand vertex group by texture aplha

Tags: texturing, modifiers, vertex-groups

I would like to ask how to expand or erode vertex group which is setting by alpha of texture. If there are non-destructive system it will be best. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what your asking but you could use a displacement modifier with a texture attached. Then extrude all the vertices out and delete them. If that's what your asking.

Comment: I would like somethink like this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76497/dilate-expand-vertex-color-mask

but with vertex group. 

I cant select vertexes by alpha and then expand the selection ...

A) maybe it can  be done with alpha itself, but i dont know how to joint compositing erode/diletate node to txture slot.

B) or I must use vertex weight edit then collapse it(apply) and after that select vertices by edit mode > select vertext group and psuh ctrl and +. But i would like to find more automated or controlled solution.

Comment: I'd suggest add that to your question @MRL

Comment: You can use a vertex weight edit modifier, modulated by a texture specified in the modifier; with the texture set up to use an image.  I'm not sure exactly what you're after, so I couldn't tell you more-- just that it sounds like that's what you should be looking at.