# Subdivide face with nice random effect

Tags: modeling

I've stumbled upon a nice assets of low poly rocks and I'd like to create a similar effect. The transition between faces for these rocks are very smooth, I wonder if there is a tool/plugin I can use to create a similar effect (image attached).

[image]
[image]

Comment: There is an add-on called Cell Fracture. But you need to manually merge faces afterward.

Comment: @SergeL exactly the problem is that I should merge all the faces together... I'm wonder if exists a similar technique that works all in once (also because I need to create much bigger objects.

Comment: @MrZak No those are single objects.

Comment: One simple way could be to use [Decimate at *Collapse* method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrvpB.jpg) after modifiers which would provide geometry for that. That won't provide that much quads as there are in the screenshots.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This 3 modifiers produce similar effect:

[image]

We have **remesh** for create huge amount of square faces, next adding randomness by **displace** with noize texture, and **decimate** for creating big irregular faces. You can tune all settings to get different results.

Maybe, instead of creating geometry, try to use texture (as you suggest voronoi):

[image]

I use node group from here: [Voronoi Cracks Fac?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52284/voronoi-cracks-fac)

Comment: Lots of triangles though :(

Answer (score 1):

First activate the cell fracture addon
[image]
You can play around with the settings untill you get somthing you like but enter 0 to the margin so it is easyer to merge the fragment.

By standard it will create the result on the next layer and if you use that one it will make things easyer if you enter a empty one for it to use.

Select the fragment and make them to one object.

[image]

Enter edit-mode and remove any doubles

[image]

Add a displaysment with some randomness

[image]

Comment: Why a negative vote? to me this solution seems good... am I missing anything?

Comment: is this resulting in a single object or multiple single rocks?

Comment: This is the result to a singel object