# Voronoi texture on cube

Tags: texturing, geometry-nodes

I would like to reproduce the Voronoi cube effect as on the photo. This is inspired with the following post:

https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/143634/163648

Would it be possible to achieve this with geometry nodes?

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5943/how-to-make-a-mosaic-plane/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/92697/subdivide-face-with-nice-random-effect/

Comment: Quite easily. fist make sure you have enough topology, then use a set position then take the normal node use it as the offset, but first scale the normal (with the scale setting in the *vector math* node) by a voronoi texture (use smooth f1 with a low smoothness value)

Comment: @shmuel

I tried to follow instructions, but not sure if correctly as this is what I get.

https://imgur.com/a/IsTooBD

Comment: @healthyfat use the color not the distance. and maybe add more subdivisions/resolution

Comment: @shmuel You are right. Switching to color and adding subdivision works. I think the result looks pretty close. Thanks.

https://imgur.com/a/Wfp2v5a