# Cycles Convolution Matrix (Kernel)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, matrix

According to this post:
[voronoi cracks fac](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52284/voronoi-cracks-fac)

Is it possible to refactor the texture and use it from outside the node group?
So it would be possible to have an Convolution Matrix Node.

P.S. Why are the 2 nodes muted?:
[image]

Comment: Questions shouldn't be aimed at one specific user.

Comment: well i tried to comment under the original thread but i can't because i have not enough points.. thats the reason why I created a whole new post.

Comment: In this case we should ask the @Jerryno (who answered the linked question) to add some feedback

Comment: yes please! but how?

Comment: This is a good question, though. But I think node system may need new features to do what you ask.

Answer (score 1):

The 1st set of nodes (add and subtract nodes) are used  for offset the coordinate .. it is 3*3 convolution filter ..so it can use 9 voronoi/image texture ..so if you adds 0.5 in one of the add node , 1 texture will offset  0.5 unit scale..
If you add/subtract 0 in those node that means that node will not offset .there are 2 add node because 1 is x axis and other one is y axis.
So if you mute those 2 add node it doesn't matter cuz it is not offseting anyway...soorry for my bad English