How can I use convolution matrix in Shader Node
I want to use a convolution matrix so that I can create a Gaussian Blur for the image without it having too much noise.
I saw someone upload it to BlendSwap and also something else here on StackExcange, but I couldn't figure out how it works. (I understood the mathematical idea, but I did not understand how it is implemented with the help of Shader Nodes)
Can someone explain to me how to do it step-by-step?
BTW, if you increase the size of the Kernel, it should increase the quality of the effect, right? Does it have any other effects besides that? (Something to do with accuracy, maybe?)

Does it answer your question ? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/97962/cycles-convolution-matrix-kernel

Not really, I didn't understand how it's works, and that's the important part...
I really need some explanation, I guess.

There already is a detailed explanation in https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52284/voronoi-cracks-fac.

It's just explain how the matrix itself working, but I didn't understood how it's implemented in the nodes...
