# How to make sharpen node in cycles material editor?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

Have anyone tried to make node (effect/filter) like in substance designer (Sharpen) in cycles?

Example:
[image: 123]

Comment: The only way to reproduce exactly what SD is doing here would be to [run a convolution matrix](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52284/voronoi-cracks-fac) over the texture in Cycles, which, IMO would be a heroic, but uneconomical way to do it

Comment: Why developers haven't yet added filter nodes like this?
This would allow the creation of more complex procedural materials

Comment: @0xFFF because use cases are rare and very specialized, it would be hard to develop something that is useful to many people. These things are perfect example of additional community created value where the Blender itself only caters to making node environment flexible and robust enough to allow for complex setups.

Comment: it would actually be pretty useful to write a little OSL node to run a 2  or 3D convolution matrix of the user's choice over  2 or 3D  textures; I think it would significantly expand the range of procedural textures that could be cooked up reasonably quickly ..

Comment: I found some material on this topic. 5x5 Convolve for Cycles Nodes Materials
There is a 5x5 convolution matrix with a few kernels provided: Sharpen, Box Blur, Gaussian Blur, Edge Detect, and Emboss.
[Download scene from Blendswap](https://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/90979)