# Gaussian Blur Blender Material Node

Tags: node-editor, blur

I was wondering if there is a way to do Gaussian Blur effect on a generated texture in blender. Currently I blur images by mixing gain and then subtract them from the vector but this creates more a a distortion effect.

I tried finding a way to average pixels but I this does not seem possible in the node editor.

Does anyone know how I can tackle this problem?

Comment: One of the links here have a node called "ImageBlur" It works really well. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/9394/how-to-blur-a-texture-node-in-cycles-material

Comment: @icYou520 yes that is the same method I used. Mixing a noise texture and then subtract them both. What I try to do is a Gaussian Blur ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_blur )

Comment: That ImageBlur node does have gaussian blur distribution. Why is it not working for you?

Comment: It add/removes pixels based on noise, so if I use it for displacement texture ( one that is created procedural ) it creates highs and lows based on the noise. What I try to do is to have a method that takes averages color values based on a range of neighbor pixels.

Comment: There's a heroic node implementation of a 3x3 convolution kernel [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/52326/35559), You could, with patience, plug in the right matrix.

Comment: That is a great start! Will write an update when I made it work.

Answer (score -2):

You can go to the compositor and add a blue node, set it to fast gaussian and enable relative, then set the x and y values to suit your needs.
Make sure you connect an image pipe to it though... if your using Images, you can find an image node in inputs category in the composition menu

Comment: Thats in the compositor not in the materials.