# Creating lines in procedural voronoi cell texture

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, node-editor, shaders, height-map

I've been trying to figure out how to make a kind of crackle map similar to this:

[image]

Using this: the Voronoi cells texture in cycles:

[image]

My theory is that you could use the information in the texture (the places where the different colors meet) to create black lines, but I just cannot figure it out.

Any examples would be appreciated.

Comment: it looks like you have some answers here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52284/voronoi-cracks-fac

Comment: allright, thanks a bunch @moonboots