# Edge Detect / Edge Outline for a procedural grayscale texture (material setup question)

Tags: materials, node-editor, procedural

I'm working on a procedural material and got stuck with the following issue. My material generates a high contrast grayscale mask which is used to blend layers. I need to break up the edges of this mask with noise. In order to do that I gotta have some edge detect node setup. In Substance Designer there's is a special Edge Detect node for this which is based on blurring the input texture. In UE4 this can be done by "If" node and other methods. However, in Blender, there is no blur node or logic operators. The best I could do is the example below. It is not good enough, because the outline is too narrow and there is no control over its width. I will be grateful for any ideas on a better node setup. Examples illustrated below.

**Desired effect from Substance Designer**

[image]

**Blender - Original Generated Mask Texture**

[image]

**Blender - Lousy Edge Detect Setup**

[image]

[image]

Comment: If the bricky-mask texture we see is procedural,  the edge-marking may be possible further back down the tree, inside the group? 2D convolution with nodes is [possible](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/52326/35559), but.....

Comment: @RobinBetts, yes, the texture is generated, not an image texture. The group is just made by me for the ease of use of 'Edge Detect' node, it just takes the generated texture as input from the master graph. Thanks for the link - will try it, looks complicated though

Comment: There are convolution nodes created by community, but they work with image textures that take vector inputs. Is it possible to make the generated texture to have vector input?

Comment: The procedural texture _must_ have a vector input (a definition of a texture space) _somewhere_,  otherwise it wouldn't know what was where, If the group has no explicit  vector input, it will either be using the default 'Generated' texture space, or referring to some other space somewhere in its tree. Can you share it?

Comment: @RobinBetts I attached the blend file above. Had to delete all textures and geo in order to comply with size limitation. Hope it will be helpful. Frankly, I'm very surprised (in a bad way) that such obvious things as blur and edge detect are not supported. Sounds silly, but thinking about painting edge break up manually.