# Is it possible to create a Gaussian Pass Filter in Material Nodes?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor, effects, shader-nodes

I noticed someone did something of an image kernel here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/52326/94245

I was wondering if something similar is possible with a gaussian kernel to achieve TRUE gaussian blurring in material nodes?

I want to be able to blur noise textures and similar vector data.

So far the best Ive seen is using white noise and other such data to get "close" to gaussian, but more of a "noisy" gaussian (Credit to jocafa for the nodes)

[image]